# Formatting PHP text for use in Javascript variable

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am having a tough time covering all areas with special chars that could possibly break the variable in JavaScript. So for context I am pulling information from a database and then echoing it to JavaScript variable that will display the data which is text that has been entered by a user and stored to the table.

The php variable is $letter see the code below that I used to try to keep it from breaking

```
$letter = $order["letter"];
$letter = str_replace("'", "\'", $letter);
$letter = str_replace("\"", "\"", $letter);
$letter = str_replace("\r\n", "\\n",$letter);
```

Below is the line of code where I attempt to decode it so that it will display in an html format

```
$(".fa-eye").click(function () {
            //clear pager html
            $(".pager").html('');
            $("#text-pager").html('<p class="text-left prevdescription"></p>');
            //clear pager html
            var parentTd = $(this).parent().parent('td');
            var letterContent = parentTd.find('#letterTxt').val();
            var pagerHtml = '<p class="controls"><a class="tp-control-arrow-left unactive"><span><</span></a><a class="tp-control-arrow-right"><span>></span></a><ul class="pager"></ul></p>';
            $(".prevdescription").html(letterContent.replace(/\r?\n/g, '<br/>'));
```

It produces the output in the image below...what am I missing?

```
You may write me down in history\nWith your bitter, twisted lies,\nYou may tread me in the very dirt\nBut still, like dust, I\ ............. This is what it outputs. not showing all of the content.
```

[image]

Comment: Can you show how you're using `$letter` in the HTML?

Comment: I would encourage you to convert your data into JSON via `json_encode()` in PHP before sending it to JavaScript. It will help address all this for you.

Answer (score 0):

Use `json_encode()`, it converts a PHP value to the equivalent JavaScript literal.

```
<script>
var letter = <?php echo json_encode($order['letter']); ?>;
</script>
```